# UIView animateWithDuration: duration: animations: completion: seems to have a default transition?

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiview

In my program, I want to create an animation that will move at a constant speed. It appears that the animation starts slowly, speeds up and then finishes slowly. Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can change this setting by using the `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` alternative. Send an `UIViewAnimationOption` mask for the option parameter. These are the options that you're interested in :

```
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn   
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
```

The documentation says that `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` is the default value.

See the documentation for more details : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Answer (score 21):

You should use, that will solve your problem

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
        //code with animation
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //code for completion
    }];
```